# Is it possible to save already loaded content while developing chrome extension without making another download request?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing chrome extension to save content which is already  downloaded by chrome, I am using chrome download api for saving already downloaded content,  but it makes one more request of download. I want to save content without making one more request of download. kindly give me solution on it..

```
         chrome.downloads.download({
            url: fileUrl,
            filename:"extdown/"+filepath ,
            conflictAction:"overwrite",
            saveAs:false
        },function (downloadId, err) {
            if(downloadId)
            {
                console.log(downloadId)
            }else
            {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
```

Comment: Can you use `localStorage` or `IndexedDB`?

Comment: still, I didn't use, is it possible by localstorage or indexed Db?

Comment: are you sure the request is not being fufilled via http cache? it should say in devtool's network tab...

Comment: I am not able to see the request details on devTools network tab while using chrome download api.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download file's content using `window.fetch` with  suitable [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache) value. 
Then create a blob URL with that data and download it with `chrome.downloads.download`.

Comment: I tried it, but it goes in infinite loop in background. can you help me or give any code sample?